# Selected value in drop down returning undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to select a value from the drop down and pass the value in the JavaScript function. But in the JavaScript function i'm getting the value undefined. How can i resolve this?
Here goes the html

```
<div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span id="search_concept">All</span> <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="chooser" role="menu" onclick="dropDown_chooser()">
      <li value="type"><a href="#">Type</a></li>
      <li value="loc"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
      <li value="name"><a href="#">Name</a></li>
      <li value="sal"><a href="#">Salary</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and the javaScript

```
function dropDown_chooser() {
    var select = document.getElementById("chooser");
    var select_val = select.value;
    console.log("select val" + select_val);
}
```

Comment: there is no drop down here

Comment: you should use <select> and <option> tags.

Comment: You're trying to access li value which has no value (only form controls have values). You would need to access the attribute instead to get the li value.

Comment: A dropdown is created using `<select>` and `<option>`. If you use some custom dropdown stuff that uses a `<ul>`, you'll also need a custom way to get the selected `<li>`. A `<ul>` doesn't have a `value`.

Comment: Are you using any plugin to create a dropdown from ul? if so you can get how to read the value from it's documentation.

Comment: Actually i'm using the dropdown beside a search box so that i can search according to the item that is selected from the dropdown. I couldn't do it using <select>  <option> so, i used <ul> <li>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using bootstrap by looking at the classes you have used; you can go with the following code then

```
<div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="search_concept">All</span>                      
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="chooser" role="menu">
        <li value="type"><a href="#">Type</a></li>
        <li value="loc"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        <li value="name"><a href="#">Name</a></li>
        <li value="sal"><a href="#">Salary</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var param = $(this).parent('li').attr("value");
        var concept = $(this).text();
        $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
        console.log("select val = " + param);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('#chooser > li');
dropdown.forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener('click',function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span id="search_concept">All</span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="chooser" role="menu">
    <li value="type"><a href="#">Type</a></li>
    <li value="loc"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    <li value="name"><a href="#">Name</a></li>
    <li value="sal"><a href="#">Salary</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this is not a dropdown menu ,using "select" and 
"option" is the proper way and you should use "onchange" instead of "onclick". 
I posted it, like this it works, hope this helps!

```js
function getvalue(){
    var skillsSelect = document.getElementById("chooser");
    var selectedText = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(selectedText);
    alert(selectedText);
    }
```

```html
<div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
   <select class="dropdown-menu" id="chooser" role="menu" 
       onchange="getvalue()">
      <option value="type"><a href="#">Type</option>
      <option value="loc"><a href="#">Location</option>
      <option value="name"><a href="#">Name</option>
      <option value="sal"><a href="#">Salary</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

.

Comment: Actually i'm using the dropdown beside a search box so that i can search according to the item that is selected from the dropdown. when i paste your code there it only shows the search box without the dropdown

Comment: all i have is the dropdown